# java generics/inheritance in nested hashmap

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, hashmap

if i have two hashmaps, of types

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Police>> time_id_police;  
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Ambulance>> time_id_ambulance;
```

where Police and Ambulance both extend Rescue, how can i have a method like

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Rescue>> getRescue(){
   if (a) return time_id_police;
   else return time_id_ambulance;
}
```

neither this, nor changing the return type to

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ? extends Rescue>>
```

seems to work.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Rescue>>` is wrong because then a value could be replaced in `time_id_police` with a `HashMap<Integer, Ambulance>`. A similar thing could be done if you replaced `Rescue` with `? extends Rescue`.

However, using `? extends` twice gives us something that wont break the type system.

```
HashMap<Integer, ? extends HashMap<Integer, ? extends Rescue>> getRescue() {
```

Most Java programmers prefer to use the more general `Map` in types rather than a specific implementation.

```
Map<Integer, ? extends Map<Integer, ? extends Rescue>> getRescue() {
```

Incidentally, if you change the body of your method to use the more concise ternary operator:

```
   return a ? time_id_police : time_id_ambulance;
```

You get a slightly more helpful error message, as the compiler works out the type for you:

```
R.java:18: incompatible types
found   : java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer,capture of ? extends java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer,? extends Rescue>>
required: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer,java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer,Rescue>>
   return a ? time_id_police : time_id_ambulance;
        ^
1 error
```

Comment: just what i wanted. rather verbose though, because the real map is 5 levels deep :) thanks a lot

Comment: I don't exactly know what you are doing, but perhaps it might be worth introducing a key object - a single object composing the fives keys you would use for your nested maps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your declarations of time_id_police and time_id_ambulance to

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Rescue>> time_id_police;
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Rescue>> time_id_ambulance;
```

you might also want to declare them as Map instead of HashMap, this way if you ever decide to change the Map implementation you use, you'll only have to make a change in one place (where you instanciate your object) rather than in many places (where you use your object)

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Rescue>> time_id_police = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Rescue>>();
```

Comment: With these changes how can you be sure that no Ambulance is put into time_id_police ?

Comment: @Zed, you can't.  The best workaround might be to create a wrapper class that hides the implementation details from the users of the police and ambulance collections

Comment: @Tom, how so?  I don't see a problem, but I am having a slow day, so that means nothing

Comment: Well you would still want to be able to do `time_id_police.get(x).get(y)` and still end up with `Police` and not just `Rescue`.

Comment: @Tom, yup, having a slow day.  I see what you mean.